# One liner to use lines of a file as parameters for a command from linux shell

Tags: linux, version-control, csh

I have a file full of file names such as :

> modified_files.txt
>
> ```
> mydir/file1.cpp
> mydir/file2.cpp
> mydir/file3.cpp
> ```

I have a VCS that has a check-in syntax as follows:

> mytool checkin -c "comment" filename

Is there a simple way of outputing the lines of modified_files.txt to the end parameter of my VCS tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the following the line.
When the echoes look nice, remove the echo and you're done.

```
cat modified_files.txt | xargs echo mytool checkin -c "comment"
```

Comment: or even `xargs -a modified_files.txt mytool checkin -c "comment"`... to spare another `cat` for more appropriate feline pursuits...